# How to apply the length condition on the existing regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a regular expression of `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+[ ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/` in Javascript and now I want to restrict/test the input string length to be in the range of 2 to 30 characters. How can I enforce/add `{2,30}` (which according to my basic knowledge checks for inputs of length between 2 and 30) to an existing regular expression in my case for the above mentioned regular expression.

Comment: Where you're facing problem.

Comment: show us some input and expected output

Comment: I want to test input for lengths of range 2-30. I have tried /^[[0-9a-zA-Z]+[ ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*]{2,30}$/ but its accepting input strings greater than 30 as well.

Comment: Use a positive lookahead to check the length and use a quantifier for the second character class `^(?=.{2,30}$)[0-9a-zA-Z]+[ ][0-9a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: the final output string should be something like alphanumberic characters followed by space and followed by 0 or more alpha numeric characters. and the overall length has to be in the range of 2,30.

Comment: Can there be a space at the end?

Comment: No, But there can be a space in the middle.

Comment: Can be or must be? And a single space or multiple spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=.{2,30}$)` to check for the number of characters and you have to use a quantifier `+` for the character class in the middle character class and add matching the ranges as well.

If there can be multiple spaces:

```
^(?=.{2,30}$)[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]$
```

That will match

- `^` Start
- `(?=.{2,30}$)` Positive lookahead to assert 2-30 characters
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]` Match one of the char class
- `[0-9a-zA-Z ]*` Match 0+ times any of the char class including a space
- `[0-9a-zA-Z]` Match one of the char class
- `$` End

**Edit**

Without a lookahead this can also be written as

`^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,28}[A-Za-z0-9]$`

Comment: The second regex you suggested solves my problem. I do have a question, if I want to make the second character class as an optional ^(?=.{2,30}$)[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*$ is this the change that would reflect it.

Comment: Note that if you make it optional then the string can end with a whitespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand but ..

```
/^([0-9a-zA-Z]+[ ][0-9a-zA-Z]){2,30}$/
```

??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but what is wrong with simply using `^[0-9a-zA-Z]{2,30}$` ?

You can make assertions using lookaheads to check for length.

e.g. add `(?!.{31,})` to the start of your regex after `^` which is a negative lookahead saying if there are 31 or more of any character then do not match. This isn't necessary for this case though. I would use something like this in password validation for example. e.g. `(?=.{8,})` is an assertion that it has to be at least 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Avinash,
You need to restrict the Regex to only grab the first 30 characters. Regex for that can be as follows.

**Regex:**
`[\w\s]{2,30}` here \w matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

**Example:**
https://regex101.com/r/mN825k/1

If you do not want to include `_` you can use this regex instead.
**Regex:**
`[A-z0-9\s]{2,30}`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/mN825k/2

Both the cases also includes spaces. If you do not want space to be part of your string and split the string after space remove `\s` from the regex.